# Customize {{#markdown}} behavior in Meteor

Tags: meteor, markdown, showdown

I love Markdown. The concept is one of the most elegant and useful I've come across in my few years as a programmer. So I was excited to see Meteor implement a Showdown package and let me use it with the `{{#markdown}}` block helper.

However, when I started using it, my **least** favorite gotcha of markdown suddenly appeared: Indented Code Blocks.

Writing this:

```
<template name="home">
    {{#markdown}}
        Hello!!! Welcome to *My Site*!!
    {{/markdown}}
</template>
```

Results in this:

> `My Hello!!! Welcome to *My Site*!!`

Formatted as CODE!!!!

I hate indented code blocks. They completely screw with attempts to actually *use* Markdown in a programming environment. Code is wildly indented, and for good reasons. It keeps things organized and makes behavior clear. So the fact that Markdown specifications have for years missed this is flabbergasting to me. Github's fenced code blocks are an **infinitely** more intelligent way to do this, since it doesn't require repetitive punching of the tab or space key, making it easier to edit, and it's clearer what's happening in the text.

Anyway, `</rant>`.

I want to customize the markdown being used by meteor. How?? I've looked through [Atmosphere](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/) and searched markdown, and found nothing applicable. Also, I'm not sure how to use a Showdown extension in the meteor environment.

Any solutions welcome!! All I really want is a markdown implementation that doesn't have indented code blocks. They're stupid.

Comment: You could do this instead: `{{#markdown}}Hello!!! Welcome to *My Site*!!{{/markdown}}` (No Newlines/Indents/spacing between `{{#markdown}}` and your markdown content`

Comment: Well yeah I know, but I want to be able to do LOTS of Markdown all over my site, within other block elements, with block elements within it, etc.

Comment: To customize the markdown package you need to add it in manually in `/packages` from https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/showdown. (In a showdown directory). You can then customize it in the way you wish. The `showdown.js` file is commented in great detail so it shouldn't be very hard to navigate through a custom display.

Comment: I get no results when i use {{#markdown}} {{data}} {{/markdown}}, but i can access {{data}} outside markdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not implement your very own `markdown` helper:

```
// this is based on showdown package in spark branch
Handlebars.registerHelper('markdown', function (options) {
  return UI.block(function () {
    var self = this;
    return function () {
      var renderer = new marked.Renderer();
      var text = UI.toRawText(self.__content, self /* parentComponent */);
      return HTML.Raw(marked(trimIndentation(text), { renderer: renderer }));
    };
  });
});
```

where `trimIndentation` can look more or less like this:

```
function trimIndentation(text) {
  var regexp = null,
      result = "";
  return text.split('\n').map(function (line) {
    var match = (regexp || /(\s*)(\s*[^\s]+.*)/).exec(line);
    if (match) {
      !regexp && (regexp = new RegExp("(\\s{" + match[1].length + "})(.*)"));
      return match[2];
    }
    return line;
  }).join('\n');
}
```

In the above example I used the syntax of the new templating engine as well as I used the [marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked) library instead of good old **showdown** (or should I say **pagedown**?), but you can of course do the same thing with a setup of your own choice.

Comment: Cool! Definitely more work, but I'll get to that once everything else is finished!

Answer (score 0):

Markdown has been [deprecated](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/ffcfa5062cf1bf8a64ea64fef681ffcd99fe7939/packages/deprecated/markdown) it seems. You could replace the native markdown with [markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it):

Install dependencies, `npm install markdown-it markdown-it-attrs` .
and setup markdown-it as your new default markdown Spacebar.

```
var md = require('markdown-it')();
var markdownItAttrs = require('markdown-it-attrs');
md.use(markdownItAttrs);
// md.disable("code")
```

You can decide what [rules](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/motion-markdown-it/4.2.2.0/MarkdownIt/RulesBlock) you want to disable or edit. In my case i disabled code blocks, but you can check out documentation for your own cases.

And then implement markdown as spacebar:

```
  Blaze.Template.registerHelper("markdown", new Template('markdown', function () {
    var view = this;
    var content = '';
    if (view.templateContentBlock) {
      content = Blaze._toText(view.templateContentBlock, HTML.TEXTMODE.STRING);
    }
    return HTML.Raw(md.render(content));
  }));
```

Be sure to remove markdown (`meteor remove markdown`) before implementing your version.

You can then call it using `{{#markdown}}` spacebar.