# Meteor Markdown shows only the first line

Tags: meteor, markdown, highlight.js

I want to highlight my code. So I use `simple:highlight.js`and `markdown`packages. However only the first line will be highlighted and the rest of the code is shown as blank text outside `<pre>` tags.

**TEMPLATE**

```
    <div class="card">
        <p class="front">
            {{#if cards.frontIsCode}}
{{#markdown}}
    {{cards.front}}
{{/markdown}}
            {{else}}
                {{cards.front}}
            {{/if}}
        </p>
    </div>
```

**RENDERED HTML**

```
<p class="front">

<pre><code class="hljs javascript"><span class="hljs-keyword">var</span> x = <span class="hljs-number">10</span>;
</code></pre>

<p>var y = z;
var func = function(block) {
return block * x;
}</p>

</p>
```

The object looks like this "front: "var x = 10;↵var y = z;↵var func = function(block) {↵return block * x;↵}""

The whole repo is here: https://github.com/mvaisanen/flashcards

Comment: Please read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21759414/customize-markdown-behavior-in-meteor/21768468#21768468) and see if it helps.

Comment: I would suggest using the triple-backquote method instead of using indentation to specify code.

Comment: @stubailo what do you mean? Where should I put triple-backquotes?

Comment: like in the example here: https://atmospherejs.com/simple/highlight.js

Comment: Thanks! I got it working and I feel stupid ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's simply because your indent!!

things like

```
{{#markdown}}
    {{cards.front}}
{{/markdown}}
```

won't work, however

```
{{#markdown}}
{{cards.front}}
{{/markdown}}
```

works properly.

Do **NOT** apply any intends even in the html template.

Hope it helps